# ember js, how can i use the array in the controllers from the routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Hi I am new to ember and I want to use deal with some data in a array fetched from my server side. But I do not know how to do that. The below code is in routes.

```
searchList: null,

model: function() {

  // This is so that we don't refresh it all the time
  // arguably, this is a hack.
  var searchList = this.get('searchList');

  if(searchList !== null) {
    return searchList;
  }

  var self = this;
  return Ember.$.ajax({
    url: 'http://coen268.peterbergstrom.com/timezones.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
  }).then(function(response) {
    var cities = [];  <-----------------------this is an array of names from server side
    if (response && response.length) {
      for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++) {
        cities.push(Ember.Object.create(response[i]));
      }
    }
    /*
    cities.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.id - b.id
    })
    */
    self.set('searchList', cities);
    return cities;
```

I just want to use the cities var in my controller so that I can do something like sort, add and reorganize the output to final view html.

Many thanks!

Comment: What ever u return in the model hook becomes the model in the controller. If you are using a object, extend a ObjectController. if you are return an array, extend a ArrayController. If you dont do any of these, ember will just create one for you based on the type of the data you return.

Comment: You have a nested `return` in your `return Ember.$.ajax({})` which is not very safe... Plus you don't have to create an Object from your response to fill your cities array.

Answer (score 0):

If your route is called, say `App.CitiesRoute`, then you need to declare your CitiesController like this:

```
App.CitiesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});
```

You can then use [sorting](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/#toc_sorting) with simple Controller properties, or [filtering](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#method_filter) when calling `filter()` on `this` (which refers to your ArrayController), as shown on Ember's Guides,

You also have access to all functions and properties of ArrayController, as shown in the [Ember API documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html).

You can even specify a specific Controller for a every item of your array by specifying the `itemController`property in your ArrayController, like:

```
App.CitiesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'city'
});

// Here you can specify an ObjectController linked to all your items in the cities array

App.CityController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  cityNameLowercase: function() {
    return this.get('cityName').toLowerCase();
  }.property('cityName')
});
```

which will be bound to each city of your array.